# Zoom API for PMI

Tags: api, zoom-sdk

I'm trying to create a Zoom personal zoom meeting from Zoom API.
But Zoom API response is confusing, what data field means correct zoom meeting id for PMI.

Please let me know what field is correct between "id" and "pmi"?

Comment: I received an answer from Zoom support. Use "pmi" instead of  "id"

Comment: Hi guys. When use the PMI instead meeting ID, you cannot modified a meeting or delete it. use normal meeting ID. still can getting id or pmi and full control for a meeting